# php search form and url rewrite/formatting

Tags: .htaccess, url, search, url-rewriting

So I'm working on a self project of mine and it is related to
job searching. I want the urls to appear as:
site.com/search/developer where developer is
the search keyword obviously. Now the thing
is that as normally when I click search (the
submit button does it's job) and the url appears
as:
site.com/search.php?kword=developer and Im sure
htaccess rewrite cannot change the way php forms
behave and how they format the url.

Now I have an idea to use javascript so that when
user types a keyword, i take that and redirect the
page via js to site.com/search/[keyword] but I'm
UNSURE if this is a good idea (considering disabled
javascript cases).

Is there any decent/recommended way to achieve what
I'm trying to achieve, I know there is because I have
seen some big websites do it only I dont know what's
the best way to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly use Javascript to make it `site.com/search/developer`. For the extreme rare case when Javascript is disabled you can let them submit regular HTML form with the final URL as `site.com/search.php?kword=developer`.

Good news is that using mod_rewrite you can handle both the cases to always have pretty URL in the browser.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# internal forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.+?)/?$ /search.php?kword=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# external rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?kword=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply. I neeed to confirm what was the best approach to solving this situation. And hey thanks for the htaccess code too and for the recommendations.